# Number of 10-digit binary strings with 6 ones, 4 zeros and no consecutive zeros

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is $\binom{7}{4}$ but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place 6 ones in a row first:

`.1.1.1.1.1.1.`

where the .'s (there are 7) are places where we can put either a single 0 or nothing.
Note that 2 zeroes is not allowed (as a condition of the problem).

We have to put 4 zeroes on 7 candidate places, hence $\binom{7}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Henno's answer gives a great combinatorics trick, but I wanted to share another one, which works nicely when you want to separate each zero by at least $n$ ones (and for this case $n = 1$).

First add $n$ more $1$s (which we'll get rid of later). Then make compound elements out of each zero, being $0$ followed by $n$ ones. Then count the arrangements of the compound elements and the remaining $1$s and for the actual resulting arrangement in any given case, disregard the last $n$ characters - which are all $1$s.

So for your example:
$$0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1 \\
\to 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,\color{red}1 \\
\to \color{blue}{01,01,01,01},1,1,1 \\
\text{ count arrangements: }{7 \choose 4} \\
$$

For an example with $15 \times 1, 4 \times 0, $ and requiring $0$s to be separated by at least three $1$s,

$$
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 \\
\to 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\color{red}{1,1,1} \\
\to \color{blue}{0111,0111,0111,0111},1,1,1,1,1,1 \\
\text{ count arrangements: }{10 \choose 4} \\$$

Comment: Nice. Another way I like is to make blocks (note the "short" last one):

$\boxed{0111}\;\boxed{0111}\;\boxed{0111}\;\boxed{0} +\;six\;remaining\; 1's = 10\;objects$

and place the boxes in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways with the "short" box last.

Comment: Maybe not so easy to argue with three different types of object, but essentially you're just trimming a different way, and of course the numbers come out right :-)

Comment: Any example with 3 types of objects that you have in mind ?

Comment: I just meant that the three types of object in that case are (superficially) $\fbox{0111},\fbox{0},$ and $\fbox{1}$ - which requires a little more explanation. Of course it works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't have consecutive $0$'s, any two of the four $0$'s are separated by at least one $1$.  By placing a $1$ between each pair of consecutive $0$'s, we obtain the string $0101010$.  We need to add three $1$'s to this string.  There are $5$ places in which to add the three $1$'s, namely before each of the zeros and after the last zero.  The number of ways to distribute three $1$'s into $5$ places is ${5+3-1 \choose 3} = {7 \choose 3}$.

Comment: Nice, +1, another variation of "locking" some $1$s onto $0$s, since insertion is forbidden in the space in "$10$" (to avoid double-counting of course) so the pre-insertion string looks like $\fbox{0}\fbox{10}\fbox{10}\fbox{10}$